# Deleting tables in HTML using regex in Notepad++

Tags: regexp-replace

Very simple issue, but I am no coder.
I need to process 800 html files to remove "navigation tables" with links inside at the beginning of the file right after the word `<body>`, for example:

```
<body>
    <table align="center" border="3" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" bordercolor="663300" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>James Fenimore Cooper Society Website<br />This page is: http://jfcoopersociety.org/drama/venitienne.htm</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I want to go through all subdirectories and for each .html file,
find `<body> <table`
select all including `<table` to include everything up to `</table>`
delete selection

Another way to put it is to select all and replace with `<body>` only.

Tried this but it didn't find what I wanted:

`<body>[\s\S]*?<table>[\s\S]*?</table>`

replace it with `<body>`.

Answer (score 0):

With the disclaimer that using regex on HTML can be dangerous (so test very carefully before running it on 800 files!), use this regex in the "Find What" box: `(<body>)\s*?<table.*?</table>` and `$1` in the "Replace with" box and make sure to check the ". matches newline" so the regex will be multiline.

The $1 refers to the "saved" group in parens.

This will find `<body>` (and save it in a group) followed by zero or more optional whitespace characters  followed by an opening table tag, then zero or more non-greedy characters until a closing table tag and replace it with the first remembered group.